# AngularJS error: Module 'ngCsv' is not available

Tags: angularjs, npm

I have two computers running the identical code pulled from github. Both computers are running on Ubuntu 16 and everything was fine until a new dependency (`ngCsv`) was added to the code. Since then, I get following error but only on one machine:

```
angular.js:4053 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module lergoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCsv due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCsv' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Install ngCsv using npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngcsv) and add the ngCsv moduleName in your dependency injection.

Comment: thanks Amir, but it doesn't seem to help. I did npm install --save ngcsv, which added it to the package.json - the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by deleting the entire folder and cloning from github